# How can I allow OneTrust to scan my IPs protected website?

Tags: testing, privacy, one-trust

I have a pre-production site which is not publicly opened. We access it thanks to an IPs whitelist. I need to let OneTrust scan it to configure it before opening the site publicly.

Does OneTrust has a list of IPs that I could add to my IPs whitelist ?